# How to check if there is a hole/Cut in the screen?

Tags: android, user-interface

In the latest version of Samsung, there is a camera on top of the screen

[image: Phone with a cut/hole]

It only becomes a problem when you are using a full-screen mode and hiding the status bar, which is the case in my app. In my app, I actually got a button that is covered by the cam.

Is there any API that will tell me the size and the location of this hole/cut in the UI, so I will know not to place buttons there?

Comment: Isn't this covered by [Display Cutout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout) specifically https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/DisplayCutout ?

Comment: @MorrisonChang Bingo! This is it. Great

Answer (score 0):

Credits to [Morrison Chang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55148440/how-to-check-if-there-is-a-hole-in-the-screen?noredirect=1#comment97037490_55148440)

Since Android 9 (API level 28), there is support for [display cutouts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout).
To get the non-rendered area of the screen you should call to:

```
WindowInsets.getDisplayCutout()
```

One way of getting access to it, is by overriding the layout

```
@Override
public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) {
     insets.getDisplayCutout();
}
```